# Can someone help me with Recursive Function in c++?

Tags: c++, recursion

Can someone help me understand Recursive Function?

I've this exercise that tells me to discover if the first half of a number is the same of the other. **Example(123123)**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool half(int arr[], int inf, int sup)
{
   if(inf >= sup)
      return true;
   if(arr[inf] != arr[sup])
      return false;
   else
      return half(arr, inf+1, sup-1);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }


    if(half)
        cout << "YES";
    else
        cout << "NO";
}
```

Thanks for your time, and i you have something simpler in mind, just tell!

Comment: If you want general help in understanding something, this might be a wrong site. You will have better experience here if you ask a specific question.

Comment: Hint: Call your function. You just test that it exists, which it will.

Comment: Currently you don't call the `half` function and your code won't compile. Can you provide a working example and explain what results you are expecting ?

Comment: Your code doesn't *call* your recursive function. Seems you need to get familar with functions of any kind, before you try recursive ones.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, yeah I'm not familiar with functions at all. Can someone correct the code so that I understand the correct way to write functions?

Comment: If you cannot understand some code at a glance, IMHO best solution is to use a debugger. A debugger can show you values of variables while running line by line. If you are on Windows you can use [VisualStudio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) or if you are on Linux you can use [gdb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PorfLSr3DDI).

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(half)
```

should be

```
if (half(arr, 0, n))
```

Functions (recursive or not) don't work unless you **call** them.

Also your code is checking if an array is a *palindrome* e.g. {1,2,3,3,2,1}, it doesn't do what you are asking for in your question.